# Prove that if $a<1/a<b<1/b$ then $a<-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof

The following is Exercise 3.2.8 from Velleman:

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. Prove that if $a<1/a<b<1/b$ then $a<-1$.

I solved it using the hint in the back of the book but I am certain that there is a more elegant solution.

The hint was: assume $a<1/a<b<1/b$, prove that $a<0$, use it to prove $a<-1$.

Comment: I think the hint is elegant enough. How did you complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There isn't really a short way if you want to do it rigorously. Here is a straightforward method.]

Given nonzero reals $a,b$ such that $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$:

$a a^2 < \frac{1}{a} a^2$.

Thus $a^3 < a$.

Thus $(a+1)a(a-1) < 0$.

Thus $a < -1$ or $0 < a < 1$.

Similarly $b < -1$ or $0 < b < 1$.

If $0 < a < 1$:

$\frac{1}{a} > 1 > b$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $a < -1$.

Comment: I've left out the step-by-step justification but I'm sure you can fill them in since you said you got a proof already.

Comment: Note also that this method generalizes, as compared to ad-hoc tricks that may work for this particular problem but are useless for most others, like the one I gave in my comment on the other post. Also, instead of multiplying by the square of the denominator, one might consider the intervals between zeros of the denominator separately.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a<b$ and $a^{-1}<b^{-1}$, we must have $ab<0$. (Why?)
Hence, $a<0<b$.

Now from $a<a^{-1}$, we have $a^2>1$. Hence, $a<-1$.

Comment: What is the justification for your first line?

Comment: @user21820 Note that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is monotonic decreasing when $x>0$ and when $x<0$. So $a,b$ cannot be both greater than 0 or less than 0.

Comment: That's not what I consider at the level expected here. Otherwise I can directly see the answer from the question itself without any working.

Comment: Moreover, there is indeed a simple way to prove $a < 0$, because $a > 0$ gives $ab > 0$ and hence $\frac{1}{a} ab < \frac{1}{b} ab$, which contradicts $a < b$.

Comment: @user21820 A simple claim can have many simple proofs. I just proposed one possible consideration.

Comment: The point is that your proof is not a simple one if you are to write it all out properly. In the context of this book (an introductory book to mathematical proofs), it is not good to make a claim without giving adequate justification at the appropriate level.

Comment: @user21820 But how do you define the simplicity of a proof? It is not the same as shortness.

Comment: I meant that at this level there are only certain rules and axioms that can be used. These do not include inferences based on arbitrary tautologies. So in your case you would have to split into cases, say $a < 0$ or $a > 0$ and then if necessary split further into $b < 0$ or $b > 0$. Then your proof would be suitable for this level. So indeed I didn't mean shortness of proof but understandability. I could not figure out what rule you used to derive the first line, and so I asked. If I have to ask, the asker too! (When reading elementary proofs I of course must suspend all my prior knowledge.)

Comment: What if I have answered you like this: $2015<5012\Rightarrow\frac{1}{2015}>\frac{1}{5012}$? Indeed, I omitted some details, but one can easily fill in the gaps using his own knowledge, elementary or advanced.

Comment: No no you don't get me. Your first line required a proof by cases but you didn't even mention the cases. So at this level your proof is just incomplete, regardless of whether readers can fill in the missing things themselves. In fact you don't even want to use what you said in your comment, as "monotonically decreasing" needs a quantified statement and would require quantifier elimination. You also don't actually want to use functions, if not you have to use rules for constructing the function. If you actually try writing your proof formally using only axioms and rules, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I know what you mean. You ask for a rigorous proof and you did give one which already solved the problem. I gave this answer as a different approach, and I guess monotonicity is the essence of the problem. Maybe that's how the author designs the problem. One can change $f(x)=x^{-1}$ by other functions to design similar problems. I did not even intend to give a rigorous proof as yours.

Comment: Ah then I see where you are coming from. I suggest you add in a bit more detail into your answer about the use of the more general tool of looking at functional behaviour. The only reason for my complaint is just that the book by Velleman teaches how to construct proofs so it's better to make proofs clear. Certainly I agree that your kind of method generalizes elegantly to other more complex problems.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, I hoped that anyone reading through "$a<b$ and $a^{-1}<b^{-1}$" carefully must stop awhile to think how can this happen. So I will not modify the answer too much.